# angularjs 2 data sources with 1 controller?

Tags: angularjs

Ok. This one really has me stumped. Here is what I am trying to build.

I have a table. In the first `<tr>` I have it repeating data, and the last `<td>` has a button. When I click this button, I want to show a set of hidden rows underneath each repeated `<td>` tag. In those hidden rows, I want to call more data.

I'm using mysqli and php to encode the data on the DB into json, which I then populate into the cells. I can do all of this with 1 controller. However, if I want to pull data from another source, to populate into the hidden cells, I have to make another controller.

Here is the base code: (pardon the inline css, its easier for me to format it into external css after its functional)

```
            <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

        app.controller('tableCtrl_1', function($scope, $http){
            getdata();
                function getdata(){
                    $http.post("angular_data.php").success(function(data){
                        $scope.getdata = data;
                    });
                };
            });

        app.controller('tableCtrl_2', function($scope, $http){
            getdata();
                function getdata(){
                    $http.post("angular_data_2.php").success(function(data){
                        $scope.getdata = data;
                    });
                }
            });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding:0px;">
                <table class="table table-bordered" ng-controller="tableCtrl_1">
                    <tr style="height:70px;background-color:#0C4791;">
                        <th style="text-align:center;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">Flexi Floor/Low Wall</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">Cooling</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">Heating</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">Nominal Capacities(cooling/heating)</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">Pipe Length</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">List Price</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat = "getdata in getdata | filter:'Flexi Floor/Low Wall':true">
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">{{getdata.model_no_from}} + {{getdata.model_no_to}}</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">{{getdata.cooling}}</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">{{getdata.heating}}</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;"><span style="color:blue">{{getdata.nominal_cooling}}</span><span style="color:red;">{{getdata.nominal_heating}}</span></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">{{getdata.pipe_length}}</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">{{getdata.system_listPrice | currency: "£"}}</span></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;"><button class="btn btn-default btn-large btn-block">Select</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table class="table table-bordered" ng-controller="tableCtrl_2">
                    <tr ng-repeat ="getdata in getdata">
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;"  colspan="7">{{getdata.sales_description}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

The second table is just so that I could test and make sure it's pulling in data properly. (turns out it wasn't, as I had to encode in utf-8)

SO TLDR:

controller 1 pulls in main data, populates cells. Click the button in a cell, and it will show hidden cells underneath with controller 2 data.

Problems I am having: matching the secondary data to the ng-repeat of the primary data, using both data sources in one controller area.

image for visual aid:

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwjaK.png)

Comment: create a service with both data loaders: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: You don't need more controllers.  You need a service to handle this.

Comment: I agree that a service here is what will make this happen.

Comment: thanks everyone for your input!

Answer (score 0):

This is my technique working with relational data from MySql. Using the angular build in filter to march the main view. In MS access it is a main form and subform. for me I use slim framework to build easy API [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/)

Here is the $scope handle the related key.

```
  $scope.showDetail = function(saleId,saleDetails){
    $scope.dataDetails = $filter('filter')(saleDetails,{main_id:saleId},true);
  }
```

look at the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/b8mvrmEaGhRZB7Qs5MdC?p=preview)
Good luck!